# Is there another FXML element that acts like TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm trying to make a shopping cart Program using Javafx, however when using a database to display things such as name, price, picture, etc, I get stuck because there is certainly a very easy way to do this using `TableView`.

But in a real world application, items are displayed in a sort of Block that has a thumbnail, price, and other information about the product.

What can I use to take data from a database, and be able to add/display that information?

I know I can simply take make an anchor pane, with an `imageView`, a label that will take information queried from a DB, and I can do it that way, but with a `tableView` it's a simple `ObservableList` that can iterate through every item in a DB and display it, how can I do that with something other than `TableView`?

Comment: That is possible with `TableView`, or if you can take a look at `ListView`. You just have to set an appropriate cell factory via `setCellFactory()` method. You should easily be able to find examples on the web.

Comment: @GastónSaillén "I" should be capitalized.

Comment: my bad, misspelled that @DonaldDuck

Comment: You will definitely want to use a `TableView`. As @Jai pointed out, everything you are asking for is available by using a custom `CellFactory` for each cell. Definitely not the simplest concept to implement, however, so I recommend looking at a lot of examples and playing around before trying to add to your own project.